# Как осуществить поиск по имени файла при помощи bash?

Tags: bash

Всем добрый день! публикую свои вопросы на SO впервые, не судите строго. Соль вопроса в следующем: хочу написать сценарий на языке bash, который бы проверял существование файла в файловой системе.

```
#!/bin/bash
#cd /etc/
file_name=xor
if [[ -r $file_name ]]
then
    echo " $file_name exists and it readble "

else
    echo " not found((  "

fi
```

пока остановился на этом, работает прекрасно, но в пределах текущего каталога, соответственно ни в какой другой каталог он не заглядывает, можно ли как-то доработать скрипт, чтобы распространить его действие на всю ФС? Заранее спасибо

Comment: посмотрите утилиту find - это ровно то, что вам и надо

Comment: большое спасибо, попробую предложенный вами подход

Comment: Возможно подойдет [locate](https://linuxize.com/post/locate-command-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Команда

```
find /path/to/folder -name filename
```

будет искать рекурсивно в директории `/path/to/folder` файлы и директории с именем `filename`. Чтоб искать только файлы добавьте опцию `-type f`.

Comment: попробую ваш метод, спасибо